# I have added Newtonsoft.json but still i get a error Reference not found?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` and i have also downloaded `Newtonsoft.json` package but still I'm getting error

Comment: var questions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Questions>>(QuestionsText);

Comment: What project have you added this is in? and where are you trying to reference it? Make sure its the same project !

Comment: Followin gon from @NaveenRam's comment you need to specifiy the object into which you are deserializing into so if you are expecting just one object JsonConvert.DeserlizeIbject<[ReplaceWithObjectName]>([ObjecttoDeserialize]) and if you are expecting a List then JsonConvert.DeserlizeIbject<List<[ReplaceWithObjectName]>>([ObjecttoDeserialize]).

Also sometimes (if you are using Visual Studio or Andriod Studio) unload and reload the project and refresh your packages just to be sure

Comment: Could you provide code sample with error message for us to test?